# How to make exoplayer fullscreen in notched device

Tags: android

i have made a exoplayer template and used theme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
      <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
      <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
      <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
      <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
      <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
      <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
      <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
      <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
</style>
```

And used this layout for player

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/videoPlayerContainer"
    android:background="@android:color/black"  >
        <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.AspectRatioFrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/exoPlayerFrameLayout"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:resize_mode="fill">
            <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
                android:id="@+id/idExoPlayerVIew"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:show_buffering="when_playing"
                app:resize_mode="fill"
                app:show_timeout="3000"
                app:scrubber_dragged_size="25dp" />
        </com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.AspectRatioFrameLayout> 


</RelativeLayout>
```

but the player fullscreen doesnt go beyond notch i used pixel 3xl in studio
and here is the result
[image: Output view]

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by using

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
```